# Google Sheets loop VLOOKUP and concatenate results

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, flatten, google-query-language

I'm wanting to loop through a list of values in a column (ie: Value1|Value2|Value3), use those to VLOOKUP a column, then return the concatenated values into the cell.

Sheet example: **BUSINESSES.csv**

| ID | Business Name | Services | Tags | (Expected Outcome) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6259 | 22Handy | Business |  | Test1|Test2 |
| 6260 | AAFMAA Wealth | Business|Financial Management |  | Test1|Test2|Finances|Accounting|Budgeting |

Notice the "TAGS" column is empty. This is where I want to return results (and enter the formula).

The goal is to take each "Service" and look through the following separate sheet example:

Example: **SERVICES.csv**

| Service Name | Tags to add |
| --- | --- |
| Financial Management | Finances|Accounting|Budgeting |
| Business | Test|Test2 |

So if a Business has a service of "Business" then it should return "Test1|Test2"

If a business has the services "Business|Financial Management" then it should return "Test1|Test2|Finances|Accounting|Budgeting" because it is pulling tags from both of the services the business is assigned to.

I've tried different combinations of `INDEX`, `VLOOKUP`, `FILTER`, and `REGEXMATCH` but to no avail.

Something like: `=INDEX( FILTER( Services!A2:A, IF( REGEXMATCH( Services!A2:A, C2,))))......`

Comment: Have you tried TextJoin or Join with your filter?

Comment: @ScottCraner I have not. I'm not experienced enough with `FILTER` and I keep running into row/column mismatch errors. JOIN/TEXTJOIN would be perfect for writing the final output once all the looping is done though

Comment: do you have any tags that contain space?

Comment: @player0 Yes, some tags contain spaces. I could find/replace spaces into dashes or underscores if that makes creating a formula easier, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(C2:C, "|"))="",, SPLIT(C2:C, "|")), 
 {G:G, SUBSTITUTE(H:H, " ", "×")}, 2, 0))),,9^9))), " ", "|"), "×", " "))
```

[image]

Comment: Incredible! I temporarily used `=textjoin("|",true,filter(Services!$C2:$C, REGEXMATCH(Services!$A$2:$A, C2) ))` to solve the problem -- but it wasn't perfect (mainly because of "whole words" not being taken into consideration. But YOUR formula is flawless. It about 45 seconds to show values because the sheet was so huge, but it worked. Huge huge thanks to you my man!